# Can we block [bigasoft.com] from spamming our site?

Tags: support, status-completed, spam, blacklist

I'm sure I've flagged at least five answers from spam users trying to promote `bigasoft.com`. They post nothing useful per se, but include links that look like tutorials, but in the end they always tell people to buy their software.

Unfortunately, since the developers revoked the ability to search for deleted messages, I can't give a number of how many posts containing an URL with `bigasoft.com` have been deleted already.

On November 1st, there were at least [thirteen deleted](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2313553#2313553). I suspect it's at least fifteen now, if not more.

Therefore:

- Super Users should be aware of the fact that these posts are definitively spam
- Can we permanently block `bigasoft.com` posts?
- Can't we block their IPs?

Comment: Searching for deleted posts and searching more than 6 times a minute *really* should be high-rep privileges. We can delete this stuff ourselves, but cannot search for it? How are we supposed to act as "community moderators" if we don't get the tools to do it?

Comment: @DanielBeck Exactly what I was saying. Unfortunately, this *used* to be possible until [the bug that allowed users to see the number of deleted posts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/107705/159624) in search was fixed.

Comment: In fact—and I think this is ridiculous—they even debated about not allowing moderators to search for this.

Comment: Currently at 18. Brought this up back in August to the team but obviously no feedback

Comment: @slhck *diamond* moderators can search for deleted posts, but not 10K+...

Comment: @studiohack I know. I would love 10k+ to be able to search them, but it's not possible (anymore). See the linked post in my second comment.

Comment: I saw that, it seems that the ability to search deleted posts (as in actually see the posts in search, not just the total number) was never there, correct?

Comment: @studiohack Correct. I personally would opt for being able to see those deleted posts, but at least having the count would be nice for us non-moderators to do our work more efficiently. As Daniel said.

Comment: @slhck interesting that it was never there but the deleted count was. Yeah, I agree, but at the same time, Nick Craver has a point...I'm not sure which direction I would lean personally...

Comment: Great @slhck using the url in the Question title made our Twitter account spam everyone with their url :P

Comment: @IvoFlipse Now I only have to find out if that's good or bad? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can email `team@stackexchange.com` with requests for blacklists on domain names such as this.

Try to be *sure* the domain name is indeed a recurring problem before doing so, as many spam domains are quite ephemeral and last maybe one or two days before moving on...

Comment: So should I consider it done for this case or still send a mail?

Comment: seems clear for now.. http://superuser.com/search?q=url%3A%22*bigasoft*%22

Comment: Can't we block their URL? They're [posting again](http://superuser.com/a/385035/48078). The URL's always been the same over the last months.

Comment: @slhck sure, done

Comment: @slhck [They're back](http://superuser.com/a/901702/110524).