# Add a domain to the spam blacklist

Tags: support, status-declined, spam, blacklist

Recently, I've flagged as spam six answers coming from two new users containing a spam link that promise to earn clickers money. They all go to the same link, and I'm sure that there may be other ones that I've failed to notice.

Can we add that domain to the spam blacklist so that they can't spam the site anymore?

Comment: @nhinkle I still see that link in search results on the main site. Is it just a temporary caching issue?

Comment: Probably caching. Search is cached pretty heavily.

Comment: @Sathya Why didn't I get pinged in my notification box even though you edited my question? Also, though mods can't, since *developers* have access to the spam blacklist, it is still possible that a dev can overturn the declination.

Comment: unless it's really severe, blacklists aren't touched.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can we block \[bigasoft.com\] from spamming our site?](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3989/can-we-block-bigasoft-com-from-spamming-our-site) ... questions are a little different but the answer from there still applies here

Comment: @Sathya Could you close my question as a duplicate of the other? The proper way to file a domain blacklist request is to contact the SE team directly as what is mentioned there, not to post on meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moderators don't have direct access to modify the blacklist; that can only be done by developers, and is non-trivial. However, having destroyed the spamming user and spam-deleted the offending answers, the built-in spam tools should have picked up enough information to hopefully prevent any more spam from this user. If you continue to see that specific link, let us know (pinging somebody in chat is probably the easiest way, rather than a new meta post) and we can revisit the issue.

Comment: This question was for developers.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi if the problem returns the mods can inform the appropriate parties. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Oh, and by the way, it's a distributed attack from many users as I can see.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi the built-in anti-spam measures do not just look at individual user accounts, they use other factors as well.